# SQL query to compare one column with another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is for a small project I'm doing. I am trying to write a query which can do this on the following table

> ID, Name, Pledge_Amount , Pledge_payment_amt , Gift_No, Pledge_Gift_No, Pledge_Open/Closed

ID isn't unique. So, one person would have pledged some money (Pledge_Amount), would have paid the full or part of it (Pledge_payment_amt) with multiple records for the same. The Gift_no will be be the same for the same pledge/gift and will match with the Pledge_Gift_No whenever the person decides to donate. Only when the gift has been completely paid off, the status will change.

> 1, Alex, 20, 10, G1, NULL, Open
>
> 1, Alex, NULL,10, NULL, G1, Closed

And the query is:

> Find the persons with outstanding gift amounts and change their status to open/closed

So far, I have been able to do this:

```
select *
from Test_Table2 S inner join Test_Table2 F
on S.Gift_No = F.Pledge_gift_No
WHERE S.ID = F.ID;
```

Any pointers on how to go about with the rest of the query will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT S.*, SUM(Pledge_payment_amt) AS pledged
FROM Test_table2 AS recipients
LEFT JOIN Test_table2 AS pledgers
    ON recipients.Gift_no = pledgers.Pledge_gift_no
GROUP BY S.Gift_No
HAVING S.Pledge_Amount > pledged
```

This would return all the "recpients" whose required pledge_amount is greater than the amount already pledged - e.g. they haven't met their pledge goal yet.

Comment: Thank you. I undertand your logic but I just got 0 rows returned. Am I making a mistake?
SELECT recipients.*, SUM(pledgers.Pledge_payment_amt) AS pledged
FROM Test_table2  AS recipients
LEFT JOIN Test_table2 AS pledgers
ON recipients.GIFT_NO = pledgers.PLEDGE_GIFT_NO
GROUP BY recipients.GIFT_NO
HAVING recipients.Pledge_Amt > pledged;

Comment: I might have misunderstood your field naming, but the basic logic should be right.

Comment: Oh yes, I altered the field names as they threw errors before I could execute them. I'm surprised at the 0 rows returned :o

Comment: taking out the `having` line and see what does come back.

Comment: Yes. Without the having it return the same table with the one added column called pledged. The values in pledged have either 0 or NULL. I checked out manually for one row and it should be != NULL but it still shows NULL.

Comment: Alright, I tried the having with a >= and it gives all the values in pledged = 0

Comment: Marc B: Any suggestions?

Comment: if sum() is returning null, then none of the records it's summing have non-null values.

Comment: I got my mistake! I was importing it from an excel and it had some issues. Thanks @Marc B. You're awesome!